# inline javascript only executing in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

So i have a simple script to change an image when a button or tab is clicked on. The script works fine in firefox but I cant even execute anything in my script in edge and chrome. There is nothing helpful in the console log except a few warnings and some errors. Can someone help me figure this out?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
        $('#specs_button1').click(function() {
            $('#the_image').attr('src',templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/DPS-min.jpg');              
        });
        $('#specs_button2').click(function() {
            $('#the_image').attr('src',templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/FP-min.jpg');
        });
        $('#specs_button3').click(function() {
            $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/HP-min.jpg');
        });
        $('#specs_button4').click(function() {
            $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/HP_vertical-min.jpg');
        });
        $('#specs_button5').click(function() {
            $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/QP_horizontal.jpg');
        });
        $('#specs_button6').click(function() {
            $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/QP-min.jpg');
        });

        $('#specs1').click(function() {
            $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/DPS-min.jpg');
        });
        $('#specs2').click(function() {
            $('#the_image').attr('src',templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/FP-min.jpg');
            console.log("Button 2");
        });
        $('#specs3').click(function() {
            $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/HP-min.jpg');
        });
        $('#specs4').click(function() {
            $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/HP_vertical-min.jpg');
        });
        $('#specs5').click(function() {
            $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/QP_horizontal.jpg');
        });
        $('#specs6').click(function() {
            $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/QP-min.jpg');
        });
});
</script>
```

Website: [greenreview.com.au/advertise](https://greenreview.com.au/advertise)

When clicking on the accordin or the button next to it, I would like the image to change

Thanks

Comment: window.onload = jQuery(function($){ <--- what??? Why are you using window.onload and storing jQuery into it?? That does not make any sense. You should be dropping the `window.onload =` if you want to use document.ready for jQuery.

Comment: Oh ahah in a desperate attempt to get anything out of this script into my page i added that with the console.log messages. Let me clean it up. My apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the encapsulating jquery function seemed to have solved the problem.

```
        var $ = jQuery;
    $('#specs_button1').click(function() {
        $('#the_image').attr('src',templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/DPS-min.jpg');

    });
    $('#specs_button2').click(function() {
        $('#the_image').attr('src',templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/FP-min.jpg');

    });
    $('#specs_button3').click(function() {
        $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/HP-min.jpg');

    });
    $('#specs_button4').click(function() {
        $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/HP_vertical-min.jpg');

    });
    $('#specs_button5').click(function() {
        $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/QP_horizontal.jpg');

    });
    $('#specs_button6').click(function() {
        $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/QP-min.jpg');

    });

    $('#specs1').click(function() {
        $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/DPS-min.jpg');

    });
    $('#specs2').click(function() {
        $('#the_image').attr('src',templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/FP-min.jpg');

    });
    $('#specs3').click(function() {
        $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/HP-min.jpg');

    });
    $('#specs4').click(function() {
        $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/HP_vertical-min.jpg');

    });
    $('#specs5').click(function() {
        $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/QP_horizontal.jpg');

    });
    $('#specs6').click(function() {
        $('#the_image').attr('src', templateUrl+'/images/GRAdSpecs/QP-min.jpg');

    });
```

I'm not sure why this fixed it as I have the exact code on some of my other sites